# How does one verify Python script is a pure math function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, security, scripting

I have a Python project that dynamically loads Python scripts from a set of specified directories and executes an expected function off of them.  To harden the security of this application, I would like to analyze the scripts to ensure that they are just pure math functions and, therefore, not interacting with any system components such as the HDD/SDD, the network, a database, etc.  Is this even possible to do in Python?

This question has been *moved* to https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/131283/how-does-one-verify-that-a-python-script-is-a-pure-math-function, but I'm leaving this here, for now, to keep the comments and answers that have already been provided.

Comment: While you're at it, figure out if the function ever halts..

Comment: *and executes an expected function off of them.* : since you expect them, you know in advance what they are about

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ I know only the function name, inputs, and outputs.  I can't control what a user might write into that function...

Comment: I suggest you to delete your post and move it to http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ let's discuss this in chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118468/how-does-one-verify-python-script-is-a-pure-math-function

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on the Information Security SE site (which wasn't in the options provided for moving it when I attempted to do so through the proper channel).  I recreated the question here: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/131283/how-does-one-verify-that-a-python-script-is-a-pure-math-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that sandboxing to disable things like I/O, network etc.. isn't fully reliable.
Since Python doesn't have any permission system embedded, it'll be pretty hard to do what you want.

Comment: What about programmatically validating prior to import rather than sandboxing?  The most stupid but obvious way would be to whitelist the imports permitted in the scripts and then scrape each one and block any script that imports an unrecognized module.

Comment: Well, if you really care about security that's not a good solution, there will always be a workaround or tricks to make harmful scripts. If you only want some really basic security, that's a good start though.